# react-bootstrap and Panel.Body

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to React, so maybe I'm missing something here, but I want to use the `Panel` component from `react-bootstrap`. I'm following the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/#panels-basic), but getting the following behavior.

This code works:

```
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

(...)

return ( # This is inside my component's render()
    <Panel>
        Foo
    </Panel>
)
```

This code doesn't work:

```
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

(...)

return ( # This is inside my component's render()
    <Panel>
        <Panel.Body>Foo</Panel.Body>
    </Panel>
)
```

The error says: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `(ComponentName)`.

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks!

react 15.6.2,
react-bootstrap 0.31.5

Comment: Panel#
removed, replaced with Card components https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/migrating/#panel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please change to:
`import Panel from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Panel'`

When importing from `react-bootstrap` you need to import the component from the lib folder.

Comment: @petr it needs to work. take a look at: https://codesandbox.io/s/1y347ozjl7

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. It was in the particular version of `react-bootstrap`, we were using 0.31.5 and you used 0.32, so that directed me to the cause of the problem. Apparently `react-bootstrap`'s API was changed between the versions. Thank you!

Comment: Any way to debug this? I’m using v0.32.4 and still running into this issue. I can’t really figure out why it’s happening. I’ve tried importing the component as mentioned in the answer. Wondering if maybe there’s some interop issue with another library I’m using. Any help would be appreciated as I can’t really find a lot of resources on it and I’m not quite ready to open an issue on the github project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem updated my react-bootstrap version from '0.30.7' to '0.32.4'.